# c# asp.net identity and custom roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I think I am just doing something silly here.
I have used code first entity framework with asp.net identity and I set up a custom user like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser, IKey<string>
{
    [MaxLength(100)] public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string Image { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

then I updated my `DbContext` to match:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(m => m.ToTable("Users"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(m => m.ToTable("Roles"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("RoleClaims"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserClaims"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserLogins"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserRoles"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserTokens"));
}
```

All works, and the tables were created successfully.
Now I want to do the same for roles, except this time I don't need extra columns (it's the interface that is important here) so I create a new `Role` class:

```
public class Role: IdentityRole, IKey<string>
{
}
```

I then changed my `OnModelCreating` method to this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(m => m.ToTable("Users"));
    builder.Entity<Role>(m => m.ToTable("Roles"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("RoleClaims"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserClaims"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserLogins"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserRoles"));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserTokens"));
}
```

The only line that changed was `builder.Entity<Role>(m => m.ToTable("Roles"));`.
When I run `add-migration RoleChange` I expected nothing to have changed since my last migration, but instead I get this error:

> The entity type 'Role' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'IdentityRole'. Only base entity types can be mapped to a table.

Does anyone know why?
I don't understand why `User` works, but `Role` won't....

---

Here is the full context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Claim> Claims { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// For testing only
    /// </summary>
    public DatabaseContext()
    {

    }

    // ReSharper disable once SuggestBaseTypeForParameter
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>(m => m.ToTable("Users"));
        builder.Entity<Role>(m => m.ToTable("Roles"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("RoleClaims"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserClaims"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserLogins"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserRoles"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(m => m.ToTable("UserTokens"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `DataContext` class?

Comment: it's very simple. But I have added it

Comment: Try remove all migrations and create a new one from scratch. Will this work?

Comment: add your  `role` model to `IdentityDbContext<User>` like this : `IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>` string is the type of the key which is required here

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of your `Startup`? Where you add and configure Identity. You'd need something like this: `services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => /* etc... */ )`

Comment: @osmanRahimi you comment was right. Can you add it as the answer and I will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is correct, you just need to update this line

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
```

as below :

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the magic that is required. If you are interested, for my own reference I created a [repository](https://github.com/arnovb-github/ASPNetCore31WithSQLiteAndCustomIdentity) with some of these common customizations.